# post textbox values in ajax request in php on change or textbox leave

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have autocomplete address google api textbox in my form and when i select address i get the lat and long of selected address in another two textbox.

now when i select the addreess i want to pass the lat and long value in my ajax request also but every time i am getting null values.

please help me to go out of this.

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('from_address', array('required' => false,'label' => false, 'div' => false,
    'placeholder' => 'Enter from address', 'class' => 'form-control','id' => 'fromaddress'));
    ?>

     <?php echo $this->Form->input('from_lat', array('id' => 'fromlat'));  ?>
     <?php echo $this->Form->input('from_long', array('id' => 'fromlong'));  ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#fromaddress").on('change', function() {   
    ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo Router::url(array("controller" => "Orders", "action" => "searchCourier")); ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            frmlat: $("#fromlat").val(),
            frmlong: $("#fromlong").val()
        },
       dataType: "html",
       success: function(response) {
            $("#courier_locations").html(response);
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('.spinicon').hide();
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: I think values are pass before storing into selected textboxes. Check and print that values to debug before passing to ajax request

Comment: Are you sure your element id is created properly? Also put your function inside jQuery().ready(function()

Comment: i think to...so is there is any solution to sort out...bcoz i want to pass values just after selecting address from google address ...

Comment: Kaya please check in your DOM weather these hidden long & lat have some value or not after address selection

Answer (score -1):

you can call your ajax on change of lattitude and langitude dropdown

```
$("#fromlat").on('change', function() {   
ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
url: '<?php echo Router::url(array("controller" => "Orders", "action" =>    "searchCourier")); ?>',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        frmlat: $("#fromlat").val(),
        frmlong: $("#fromlong").val()
    },
   dataType: "html",
   success: function(response) {
        $("#courier_locations").html(response);
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('.spinicon').hide();
    }
});
```

});

Comment: No shahrukh this is not possible..bcoz lat and long are the hidden fields...from form...

Comment: you can trigger an onchange event on hidden fields or you can call ajax after some time interval using settimeout function like  setTimeout (ajax call here, time required for lattitude and langitude dropdown to be filled goes here );